# How to calculate the number of days between two dates?

Tags: javascript, html, date

1. I am calculating the number of days between the 'from' and 'to' date. For example, if the from date is 13/04/2010 and the to date is 15/04/2010 the result should be
2. How do I get the result using JavaScript?

Answer (score 699, accepted):

```
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2008, 1, 12);
const secondDate = new Date(2008, 1, 22);

const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
```

Comment: Warning: not all days are 24 hours long. If your date range spans a daylight saving change, you'll lose or gain an hour (typically). Use Math.round() on the result (avoid floor or ceil).

Comment: In fact i'd preffer Math.ceil here since even if 2.01 days are left saying 3 days left makes more sense that sayin 2 days left.

Comment: @Mark 's comment about using Math.round was added to code of the answer. Don't round the result again, like someone I know... (ok it was me)

Comment: Why doesn't it count it as 5 days when it's between June 1st to June 5th?

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: @Kumait What about them?

Comment: My fault, this must be handled internally in the Date object

Comment: I tested this with 2015-02-1 to 2015-03-01 and got 31 days. There's something wrong here...
EDIT: Okay yeah.. javascript months are from 0-12 so if you're getting the input from a jquery datepicker or a regular normal date, subtract 1 form the month

Comment: Note that this code still takes into account the TIME of the given dates when counting.  i.e. checking the number of days between 3PM on the 1st and 00:00:00 on the 2nd will yield zero days.

To fix this, set both dates to midnight before comparison, i.e. add: firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0); secondDate.setHours(0, 0, 0);

This way you can say daysBetween(new Date(2016,1,10,15), new Date(2016,1,11))); and still come up with 1 day difference.

Comment: Nice, it threw me for a moment that JavaScript has January as 0, so I had put a 1 thinking that was January, but it was actually February, throwing off my calculation.  Thanks for this result.

Comment: When I copied this code to my console and after hitting return, I get undefined in my console. Any reason?

Comment: @Ilyaskarim if you're using a console, you probably want to see the resulting difference. typing `diffDays` produces the expected result.

Comment: I was having an off by one error depending on the time of day, @Howard 's suggestion fixed my problem!

Comment: To prevent red squiggly lines on the last line of the above code, replace the last line with the following code: 

`const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.valueOf() - secondDate.valueOf()) / oneDay));`

Answer (score 69):

Here is a function that does this:

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    const ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    const differenceMs = Math.abs(date1 - date2);

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(differenceMs / ONE_DAY);

}
```

Comment: 1.5 days becomes 2 days with your example? use Math.floor instead

Comment: Avoid floor because it will give the wrong result if a day in the range is shorter due to daylight saving.

Comment: why alway return Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Indochina Time) ??

Comment: Better make it `Date.UTC(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate())` for both dates and use `Math.floor`?

Answer (score 31):

Here's what I use.  If you just subtract the dates, it won't work across the Daylight Savings Time Boundary (eg April 1 to April 30 or Oct 1 to Oct 31).  This drops all the hours to make sure you get a day and eliminates any DST problem by using UTC.

```
var nDays = (    Date.UTC(EndDate.getFullYear(), EndDate.getMonth(), EndDate.getDate()) -
                 Date.UTC(StartDate.getFullYear(), StartDate.getMonth(), StartDate.getDate())) / 86400000;
```

as a function:

```
function DaysBetween(StartDate, EndDate) {
  // The number of milliseconds in all UTC days (no DST)
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  // A day in UTC always lasts 24 hours (unlike in other time formats)
  const start = Date.UTC(EndDate.getFullYear(), EndDate.getMonth(), EndDate.getDate());
  const end = Date.UTC(StartDate.getFullYear(), StartDate.getMonth(), StartDate.getDate());

  // so it's safe to divide by 24 hours
  return (start - end) / oneDay;
}
```

Comment: But if you drop the hours etc., why would you still use UTC?

Comment: @RuudLenders because day in UTC always lasts 24 hours, unlike in other time formats, so it's safe do divide by 24 hours

Comment: There's something odd about this. Although I can't find a counterexample, I don't like how you're passing in local Y/M/D values into Date.UTC when you're supposed to be passing in UTC values. On a separate point, you still need to round the result because some UTC days have 86399 or 86401 seconds

Answer (score 19):

Here is my implementation:

```
function daysBetween(one, another) {
  return Math.round(Math.abs((+one) - (+another))/8.64e7);
}
```

`+<date>` does the type coercion to the integer representation and has the same effect as `<date>.getTime()` and `8.64e7` is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: The type coercion is redundant here because you already use a arithmetic operator to substract the dates (which also results in a type coercion). So you can write it like this: `Math.round(Math.abs(one - another) / 8.64e7);`

Comment: 2019 readers: if you are using typescript, the `+` is required.

Answer (score 11):

Adjusted to allow  for daylight saving differences. try this:

```
  function daysBetween(date1, date2) {

 // adjust diff for for daylight savings
 var hoursToAdjust = Math.abs(date1.getTimezoneOffset() /60) - Math.abs(date2.getTimezoneOffset() /60);
 // apply the tz offset
 date2.addHours(hoursToAdjust); 

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}

// you'll want this addHours function too 

Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to adjust for the timezone offset, the time value is in UTC. If there is a need for timezone adjustment, it can be applied directly to the minutes using `setMinutes()` rather than converting to hours and using `setHours()`. The arguments to the `set` methods should be integers. If using `setHours` and the offset is not an even multiple of hours, the value will be truncated.

Answer (score 9):

I have written this solution for another post who asked, how to calculate the difference between two dates, so I share what I have prepared:

```
// Here are the two dates to compare
var date1 = '2011-12-24';
var date2 = '2012-01-01';

// First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
date1 = date1.split('-');
date2 = date2.split('-');

// Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
date1 = new Date(date1[0], date1[1], date1[2]);
date2 = new Date(date2[0], date2[1], date2[2]);

// We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

// This is the calculated difference in seconds
var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

// in Hours
var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

// and finaly, in days :)
var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours  / 24;

alert(timeDifferenceInDays);
```

You can skip some steps in the code, I have written it so to make it easy to understand.

You'll find a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/matKX/

Comment: Note that months are zero indexed, so you should have `new Date(date1[0], --date1[1], date1[2]);`. Also, using `parseInt` will truncate the milliseconds. Simpler to just subtract the date objects and convert the difference to days: `Math.round((date1 - date2) / 8.64e7)` or if whole days are required with no rounding, just truncate the decimal part: `(date1 - date2) / 8.64e7 | 0`.

Answer (score 1):

From my little date difference calculator:

```
var startDate = new Date(2000, 1-1, 1);  // 2000-01-01
var endDate =   new Date();              // Today

// Calculate the difference of two dates in total days
function diffDays(d1, d2)
{
  var ndays;
  var tv1 = d1.valueOf();  // msec since 1970
  var tv2 = d2.valueOf();

  ndays = (tv2 - tv1) / 1000 / 86400;
  ndays = Math.round(ndays - 0.5);
  return ndays;
}
```

So you would call:

```
var nDays = diffDays(startDate, endDate);
```

(Full source at http://david.tribble.com/src/javascript/jstimespan.html.)

**Addendum**

The code can be improved by changing these lines:

```
  var tv1 = d1.getTime();  // msec since 1970
  var tv2 = d2.getTime();
```

Comment: I had to take out the - 0.5 from the round function for it to work properly for some reason, I'm thinking it was because of the minus 1 for the month since its 0 indexed