# How can I count the days between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the number of days between two dates using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

I have those dates :

```
27/09/2011
29/10/2011
```

and I'd like to return the days between those dates (in the example, should be 33 days).

How can I do it on javascript (or jquery?)?

Comment: Don't think it's mentioned in the duplicate question but you could take a look at http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}
```

http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/DaysBetween.asp

Comment: This link is dead so the answer is not available to any more

Comment: Link still works for me, added code from site in answer since link only answers do suck.

Answer (score 4):

```
var daysBetween = (Date.parse(DATE1) - Date.parse(DATE2)) / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: It should fail : if the date is IT rather than EN the value is different :O

Comment: i've just shown the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
// split the date into days, months, years array
var x = "27/09/2011".split('/')
var y = "29/10/2011".split('/')

// create date objects using year, month, day
var a = new Date(x[2],x[1],x[0])
var b = new Date(y[2],y[1],y[0])

// calculate difference between dayes
var c = ( b - a )

// convert from milliseconds to days
// multiply milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours
var d = c / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

// show what you got
alert( d )
```

Note:
I find this method safer than `Date.parse()` as you explicitly specify the date format being input (by splitting into year, month, day in the beginning). This is important to avoid ambiguity when `03/04/2008` could be `3rd of April, 2008` or `4th of March, 2008` depending what country your dates are coming from.

Comment: [Illicitly](http://dictionary.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illicit)? I think you mean [explicitly](http://dictionary.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explicit).

Comment: yes - I do mean explicitly - you are quite right