# Why this operation with date (number of days between 2 dates) return this value?

Tags: javascript, date

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript) question, I wrote "my code" (without Math.abs, I don't need it) :

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date("2011", "09", "28"); // 28 september 2011
var secondDate = new Date("2011", "09", "30"); // 30 september 2011

var notti = ((secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()) / (oneDay));
if (notti < 1)
    notti = 1;
else
    notti = Math.round(notti);

alert(notti);
```

and it print 2 (correct).

Now, If I do this :

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date("2011", "09", "28"); // 28 september 2011
var secondDate = new Date("2011", "10", "01"); // 01 october 2011

var notti = ((secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()) / (oneDay));
if (notti < 1)
    notti = 1;
else
    notti = Math.round(notti);

alert(notti);
```

it print 4. Why 4? It should be 3...
Do you know about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month argument in the date constructor (and other date methods) runs from [0.11] not [1..12] so:

```
new Date("2011", "09", "28"); // 28 september 2011
```

is actually `Fri Oct 28`, not September.

Comment: years & days are `1` based as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript months are zero based. So October has 31 days.

```
new Date("2011", "9", "31"); // October 31st
```

Answer (score 1):

Because...

```
new Date("2011", "09", "28").toString()
```

... returns:

```
Fri Oct 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

This is because JavaScript `Data` is based on the [Java Date object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [which is a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar). See also ["Puizzle 61: The Dating Game"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=RM9sLE0ntQ0C&lpg=PP1&dq=Java%20puzzlers&pg=PT177#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the book [JavaPuzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) for an explanation.