# difference between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have to simply calculate difference between two dates, and display it as integer but my code below gives errors if there are large amount of dates (more than 26) in between 2 dates, as well as if there is a date "31st" of a month in between 2 dates.

Can not find whats wrong with my code...?

The values of `'ires_sakuma_datums'` and `'ires_beigu_datums'` are set by jquery calendar picker and are displayed in the format e.g. `25-08-2012` and `17-09-2012` respectively and the result should be displayed into id `'dienu_skaits'`

Example `'ires_sakuma_datums'` is set to `28-08-2012` and `'ires_beigu_datums'` is set to `29-09-2012` and it results into `31.041666666666668` although I would expect to result into `32`

```
   function getDays()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById('ires_sakuma_datums').value;
        var y = document.getElementById('ires_beigu_datums').value;

        //assuming that the delimiter for dt time picker is a '-'.
        var arr1 = x.split('-');
        var arr2 = y.split('-');
        var dt1 = new Date();
        dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], arr1[1], arr1[0]);
        var dt2 = new Date();
        dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], arr2[1], arr2[0]);

        document.getElementById('dienu_skaits').value = (dt2.valueOf() - dt1.valueOf()) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);

document.forms['test'].elements['dienu_skaits'].focus();
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using DateJs or MomentJs for date manipulation in JavaScript.

Comment: @editor and approvers: no jQuery in sight, adding jQuery and jQuery UI tags is weird.

Comment: Your sample code would be better if you removed the references to the DOM, and focused on the date part, makes for less noise, it's irrelevant where the data comes from. Always try to created reductions that only have relevant code

Comment: You should also specify the errors you are seeing.

Comment: @raivis please edit the question with expected results and actual results, don't add it as comments

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle I created, then say what is wrong with the results there http://jsfiddle.net/qB9V3/

Comment: @raivis result looks normally. Difference is 31 and piece of days.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I'm afraid I do not know how to use jsfiddle.net but I will check it out

Comment: Just click on the link, results show up in your console, use Chrome, or FF with firebug, or IE with dev tools

Comment: I see the problem, if you diff `31-08-2012` and `1-09-2012` you get 0 days. http://jsfiddle.net/qB9V3/2/ but diff between `28-09-2012` and `29-09-2012`  is -1 http://jsfiddle.net/qB9V3/3/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571977/why-this-operation-with-date-number-of-days-between-2-dates-return-this-value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that months to be passed to `Date` are 0 based , so you have to subtract 1 from the month. http://jsfiddle.net/qB9V3/5/ Therefore, your comparison between `28-08-2012` and `29-09-2012` was actually diffing `28-09-2012` and `29-10-2012`

So your code would need to change to be

```
    var arr1 = x.split('-');
    var arr2 = y.split('-');
    var dt1 = new Date();
    dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], parseInt(arr1[1],10) -1, arr1[0]);
    var dt2 = new Date();
    dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], parseInt(arr2[1],10) - 1, arr2[0]);
```

Beware that if your dates cross daylight savings changes, the number of days in between won't be even, so you'll need to round the result

```
document.getElementById('dienu_skaits').value = Math.round( 
    (dt2 - dt1) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000) 
);
```

Comment: hmm...I just checking your suggestion but if I set for example between `23-08-2012` and `28-10-2012` then result becomes to `66.04166666666667` No clue why it turns into such number...?

Comment: @raivis That is incorrect, if you use the two dates you've given ( `23-08-2012 `and `28-10-2012`), you'll get 66 days in between, see http://jsfiddle.net/Yabba/. The case where you'll get chopped numbers is if you cross daylight savings changes. For example, if you diff `23-08-2012` and `28-11-2012`, you'll get `-97.04166666666667`, that is what you'd expect since the time changed (Daylight savings end on 2012-11-04 in the US at least).

Comment: @raivis, actually if you're in a place that follows the European Union daylight savings, than the dates you gave do cross daylight saving changes, that's why the numbers aren't even. You can account for that (roughly) by rounding the values with `Math.round`

Comment: Thanks Juan! I also thought its because of daylight savings.