# JavaScript getMonth value of Date

Tags: javascript, date

I got a function with which I want to sort the blog posts after month.

```
function sortBlogPostsAfterMonth(blogData) {
  console.log(blogData[0].createdAt);
  var blogDateFormat = new Date(blogData[0].createdAt);
  console.log(blogDateFormat.getMonth());
}
```

the output in the console in the browser is this.

```
2013-11-24T11:32:29.023Z main.js:140
10
```

Why I get as month 10 and not 11?

Nice greetings

Comment: the underlying reason is programming language starts index from 0 , means January is not 1 but 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why this operation with date (number of days between 2 dates) return this value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571977/why-this-operation-with-date-number-of-days-between-2-dates-return-this-value)

Answer (score 2):

By default javascript month starts from `0`.You need to increement it by one.Try this:

```
console.log(blogDateFormat.getMonth()+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how JS months work. They start at `0`.

See **month** on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Javascript dates are . . . confusing at best (broken at worst). While days and years are as is (they start at 1), months are zero-indexed for some reason. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: But when I do blogDateFormat.getYear() I get 113 :x so this is broken too?

Comment: getYear() is deprecated. (And indeed, it DOES return 113. Probably a relic of the Y2K bug.) Use getFullYear() instead (returns 2013). You can check out all the Date methods here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp