# jQuery UI Datepicker - Number of Days Between Dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker. I have two date fields. I would like to find the number of days difference between the two dates.

Once I have the number of days, I’d like to put said number of dasy into a textfield.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Where you get stuck in this. I mean whats your progress?

Comment: I am stuck getting the difference in number of days. I am using the date format: dd-mm-yy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `onselect` event to get dates.

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       var d1=new Date(dateText);
       // get date from other text field
       var d2=new Date($('#date2').val());
       // d2 -d1 gives result in milliseconds
       // calculate number of days by Math.abs((d2-d1)/86400000, as 24*3600*1000 = 86400000
       // and populate it to some text field #textfield
       $('#textfield').val((Math.abs((d2-d1)/86400000)));
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I have is two dickpicker textfields. In both textfields, the date format is: dd-mm-yy. I would like to be able to get the number of days. I would then like to output said number of days to another textfield to use elsewhere on the page. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: do you know what the calculation would be for dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the dateRange Datepicker instead of using 2 different Datepickers then i calculate the number of days in the range and reply it into a textfield as you needed. I hope it helps.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label>From</label>
    <input id="from" readonly="readonly" name="from" type="text" value="">
    <label>To</label>
    <input id="to" readonly="readonly" name="to" type="text" value="">
    <label>Days</label>
    <input id="days" readonly="readonly" name="days" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

**jQuery UI**

```
<script>
var from = new Date();
var to = new Date();
var dayDiff = 1;

$(function() {
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );

            if (this.id == "from"){
                from = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                if (!(to == "")){
                    update_days()
                }
            }
            if (this.id == "to"){
                to = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                update_days()
            }
        }
    });
});

function update_days(){
    dayDiff = Math.ceil((to - from) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $("#days").empty()
    $("#days").append(dayDiff)
}
</script>
```

Comment: #days didn't work for me until I changed empty and append with val('') and val('dayDiff')

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the basic formula for getting days between dates, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

> > Googling "number of days between two dates javascript" produces [this
> >     great snippet](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2008/10/24/faq-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript/) (actually all the top results are relevant to your
> >     question):
> >
> > ```
> > var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
> > var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
> > var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,22);
> >
> > var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
> > ```
>
> ### >                                                                 (This is taken from stackoverflow answer, to see in detail, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627493/1877909))

Use below code for getting the no of dates between days

```
function showDays() {
    var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $('#num_nights').val(dayss);
}

$("#arr_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays,
     onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
         var dParts = selectedDate.split('-');
         var in30Days = new Date(dParts[2] + '/' +
                        dParts[1] + '/' +
                        (+dParts[0] + 30)
               );

    $( "#dep_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", in30Days );
    }
});
$("#dep_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays,

});
```

### **Here is [MYFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/5BbGS/512/)**

Comment: if this answer helps please accept it as correct answer