# JQuery DateTimePicker UI getting total days between two datetimepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

i am trying to get the total days from the two customized DateTimePickers i've got.

I've tried this function:

```
 function dateDifference() {
if($("#fradato").val()!='' && $("#fradato").val()!='') {
var diff = ($("#fradato").datepicker("getDate") - $("#tildato").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
$("#antalldager").val(diff)
```

The problem i've got is that wherever i try to call this function, the DateTimePicker stop working. So where/how should i call this function or is there a better way to do it?

I want to display the toal days inside of this text-box:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3"     for="antalldager">Antall dager:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="antalldager" disabled>
```

Here is my html:

```
 <script>valgavdato() </script>
<div  id="visdager" style="display: none;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3" for="fradato">Book fra:</label>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class='col-sm-2'>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='input-group date'>
                      <input type="text" id="fradato" class="form-control"/>
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"  ></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="vistildato" style="display: none;">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3" for="tildato">Book til:</label>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class='col-sm-2'>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='input-group date'>
                      <input type="text" id="tildato" class="form-control" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
   $( function valgavdato() {
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    to_MaxDate = 13;    // From date + this = to maxDate

    from = $( "#fradato" )
.datepicker({
    minDate: '0+',
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1

})
.on( "change", function() {
    var PickedDate = getDate( this );
    // See that date is in UTC format.
    console.log( "From DatePicker: "+JSON.stringify(PickedDate) );

    // Process the picked date.
    var tempDay = PickedDate.getDate() + to_MaxDate; // Add a number of days to the picked date.
    var tempMonth = PickedDate.getMonth() + 1;   // Because months are zero based.
    var tempYear = PickedDate.getYear() + 1900; // Because years are 1900 based
    console.log( "Temp date: "+ tempYear+"/"+tempMonth+"/"+tempDay +" --- It may look impossible... But Date() handles it.");

    // Create a date object in a UTC format.
  var newMaxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempYear, tempMonth-1, tempDay, 0, 0, 0));
    console.log(  "New max date: : "+ JSON.stringify(newMaxDate) );

    // Set the minDate ans maxDate options.
    to.datepicker( "option", {"minDate": PickedDate, "maxDate": newMaxDate});
}),
    to = $( "#tildato" ).datepicker({
        maxDate: '14+',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    })
.on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
});

function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
    }
    return date;
}
} );

function dateDifference() {
if($("#fradato").val()!='' && $("#fradato").val()!='') {
    var diff = ($("#fradato").datepicker("getDate") - $("#tildato").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $("#antalldager").val(diff)
}
}
```

Comment: date calculates are always very tricky (too many exceptions, various month length, time zones, winter/summer time). Probably worth to look at some implementations like http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: Hmm ok i'll check it out. So i could use the Moment function, and somehow get the dates inside the moment to calculate the diffrences?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @JanisP suggest is good. You can also make a lightweight function like:

```
function dateDifference(start, end) {
  // Assume Start and End string format: dd/mm/yyyy
  var d1 = new Date(start);
  var d2 = new Date(end);
  // d2 - d1 gives result in milliseconds
  // calculate number of days by Math.abs((d2-d1)/86400000, as 24*3600*1000 = 86400000
  return Math.abs((d2-d1)/86400000)
}
```

Found this here: [jQuery UI Datepicker - Number of Days Between Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596437/jquery-ui-datepicker-number-of-days-between-dates)

**Update**

From the [jQuery UI Datepicker Select a Date Range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) example, I created this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r8wx6afk/

It calculates the number of days  only when both fields have a date during the `change` event.

Comment: Many people suggest using onSelect. But i've tried multiple ways to use onSelect, but i have not got that to work, any suggestions on how i do that in my current script?

Comment: You could execute `dateDifference()` in the `select` event of the 2nd datepicker. Will see if I can create an example from your code.

Comment: @StianJohansen I updated my answer with a working example.