# count the number of days between 2 dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var fromObj,toObj;
        fromObj=new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,  target:"inputField1",dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

        });     
        toObj=new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField2",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"

        });             

function viewAlert(){
    //what i need to put it here?   

}

    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">

<table align="center">
    <tr><td>from:</td><td><input type="text" size="12" id="inputField1" name="from" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>to:</td><td><input type="text" size="12" id="inputField2" name="to" onblur="viewAlert()" /></td></tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

I created two input fields which takes date from jsDatePicker.After entering those dates, i need to display the number of days b/w that selected dates in the alert box. For that what i need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript

Comment: do you mean the number of days?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt ya, the number of days b/w selected dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var msDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
var days = Math.round(Math.abs((fromObj.getTime() - toObj.getTime())/(msDay )));
```