# How to get the number of days between two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate the number of days between 2 date. I have check the codes given this link 
[How to calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript).

In this example if give input  2012,02,29 and 2012,03,01 it gives output as 3. Actual answer should be 1. These there any other methods to calculate the number of days between 2 dates ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works for me - remember months in JS start at 0 so here are February 29th to March 1st 2012

```js
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2012, 1, 29, 12, 0, 0, 0); // 29th of Feb at noon your timezone
var secondDate = new Date(2012, 2, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0); // 1st of March at noon

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
console.log(firstDate, "to", secondDate, "\nDifference: " + diffDays + " day");
```

Comment: damn, beat me to it... His issue is likely the 0-based month. :)

Comment: Sorry it is my fault.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and successfully wasted my half of the day for this.And finally sort out the problem.You can see the below example:

> Note:Don't forget to include the jquery script:

```js
$("#ToDate").change(function() {
  var start = new Date($('#FromDate').val());
  var end = new Date($('#ToDate').val());
  var diff = new Date(end - start);
  var days = 1;
  days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  if (days == NaN) {
    $('#TotalDays').val(0);
  } else {
    $('#TotalDays').val(days + 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<form action="{{route('leave.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  @csrf
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Apply Leave</h4>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Leave type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="leave_type" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Leave type">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="lname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Date from</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="date" min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}" name="from" class="form-control" id="FromDate">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="date" name="to" class="form-control" id="ToDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Days</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="days" class="form-control" id="TotalDays" placeholder="Number of leave days">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Reason</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea type="text" name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason">
                                        </textarea></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-top">
    <div class="card-body">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Apply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```