# Javascript calculating age in days

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

I wonder with the current date, how can I get the age in days.
For example at date 12/4/1995 returned 6435.

Is there any library function that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compose two dates and subtract them. The result will be in milliseconds, so you have to convert that to days:

```
var days = (new Date() - new Date(1995, 11, 4)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
//            (today)          (then)             (milliseconds per day)
```

You can then round `days` (and  as appropriate.

Comment: Allowing Date to parse strings into dates is not a good idea, much better to provide explicit values: `new Date(1995,11,4)`. The format you've provided is not specified in ECMA-262 and how it's parsed is implementation dependent. Also, the [specified format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (a version of ISO8601) is not supported by all browsers in use.