# Get the number of days between 2 dates using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});

$("#to").change(function () {
    var final = $("#to").datepicker("getDate");
    var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
    var days = new Date(final - start);
    alert(days);
});

<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
```

This is what I have by far, I pretend to get the number of days passed between 2 dates everytime that final date is filled. I'm having some trouble because of conversions :s

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxnMY/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe THe biggest thing is that `datepicker('getDate')` returns a Date object already, so `final` and `start` are already date objects.

Now that you have two date objects you could the code samples in the following thread to get the number of days between them

[How to calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

The following code is ripped right from the thread and google: you can fill in appropriately

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
var secondDate = new Date(2008,01,22);

var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));
```

Comment: Yes it is working. I'm just wondering if it is the rigth way to do it. Just like if it is a trick or it is a real solution

Comment: @user1148875 idk, google around, if your wondering if there is some sort of `DateDifferential` or some sort of standard language way to get the days between two dates, there doesn't look to be any.  Stackoverflow is full of answers on how to get time between two dates, there looks to be quite a few ways, i just referred you to the first one i found on so

Answer (score 0):

The following example worked fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $datepicker1 =  $( "#firstday" );
   var $datepicker2 =  $( "#lastday" );
   $datepicker1.datepicker();
   $datepicker2.datepicker({
       onClose: function() {
           var fromDate = $datepicker1.datepicker('getDate');
           var toDate = $datepicker2.datepicker('getDate');
           // date difference in millisec
           var diff = new Date(toDate - fromDate);
           // date difference in days
           var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

           alert(days);
       }
   });
});
```

Refer:- [calculate number of days between two dates in jquery datepicker](http://goo.gl/IDR3I4)