# Javascript Conditional

Tags: javascript

I recently discovered a form of using a conditional as:

```
function leftPad(res6) {return (res6 < 10)?'0'+ res6:res6;}
res6 =leftPad(res6);
```

This is fine inside a function statement. I don't know how to work with this sort of statement on it's own (without a function statement of if there is an appropriate function statement for this string).

Example: I want to have output that compares a date with todays value, if It is after today then use "since", otherwise, use "until". Once I understand how to write this statement I can compare the date values and set a variable to the proper result, to go in my output string.

Thanks

Comment: your two statements could be written as one ... `res6 = (res6 < 10)?'0'+ res6:res6;` ... does this answer your question?

Comment: ^^ What @JaromandaX said. It doesn't even need the `()`: `res6 = res6 < 10 ? '0' + res6 : res6;`

Comment: That will help clean up the code in my previous question. Thanks for that suggestion. But this current question still remains.

Comment: That type of statement is called a ternary.

Comment: Just to make it clear in basic syntactic terms, `?:` is an *operator* and when written with valid operands the whole thing is an *expression*, not a *statement*. So it goes wherever you can write an expression, which is nearly anywhere in JavaScript.

Comment: This is how I want It to work. My attempt at comparing the two values is not working.

    var one_day=1000*60*60*24; // milliseconds
    var d0 = new Date()
    var d2 = new Date("October 1, 2015 12:00:00"); // “Some Event”
    var diff2 = Math.abs(d0-d2);  // difference in milliseconds

    Var now_then2 {return (d0 < d2)?”until”:”since”;} // Not working

    var res2 =  Math.round(diff2/one_day);
    function leftPad(res2) {return (res2 < 10)?'0'+ res2:res2;}
    res2 =leftPad(res2);
    res2 + " Days “ + now_then2 + “ 10/01/2015  Some Event" +  "\n"

Answer (score 0):

What you're descibing there is the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It does not need to be in a function, and your code could be written in one line, as  T.J. Crowder  said.

```
res6 = res6 < 10 ? '0' + res6 : res6;
```

For the second part, and answering your comments, you want to use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date("October 1, 2015 12:00:00");

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
var since_until = d2 > d0 ? 'since' : 'until'; 

var sentence = "- " + diffDays + " Days " + since_until + " 10/01/2015 - Oct Pension" + "\n";
```

With reference to this question: [How to calculate the number of days between two dates using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript)

Comment: The variable is printing as the variable text name with quotes. Not sure why but obviously I have screwed up the quotation marks somehow? Thanks.  

    var d0 = new Date()
    var d2 = new Date("October 1, 2015 12:00:00"); // "Some Event"
    var now_then2 = d2 > d0 ? 'since' : 'until';  
    var diff2 = Math.abs(d0-d2);  // difference in milliseconds
    var res2 =  Math.round(diff2/one_day);
    res2 = res2 < 10 ? '0' + res2 : res2;
    "- " +  res2 + " Days “ + now_then2 + “ 10/01/2015 - Oct Pension" +"\n"+
    // Output is:
    - 05 Days “ + now_then2 + “ 10/01/2015 - Some Event

Comment: I appreciate your marking up an example. The problem I am having is that I am getting different results from the output. 

    Putting in "- " +  res6 + " Days “ + word6 + “ 11/01/2015 - Some Data
and
word6, proves that my variable word6 has correct data in It. But It prints out as a string with the variable and the quotation marks and the variable is It’s name and not It’s value.

- 36 Days “ + word6 + “ 11/01/2015 - Some Data

Comment: @levelbest you're using weird quotation marks, and that's probably the root cause of the problem. Write code in a suitable editor, or even notepad, but not a word processor such as Word. If you want to even copy and paste them, the only two types of quotation mark you should use are " and '. Some of yours are curvy ones.

Comment: Good call, thanks very much! I had to work It a few times in BBEdit, zap the gremlins, straighten the quotes, but I got there. BTW, as aside perhaps, I am doing this in TextExpander as It allows Javascript now.

Comment: @levelbest Great, glad it works. If this answers your question, consider accepting it as an answer by clicking the little tick next to the voting buttons.