# How Do I Calculate Date Difference in Javascript

Tags: date

i want to count the date difference (days only) like if i am selecting "Date From" as 08-05-2016 and then "Date To" as 08-11-2016 ... it will calculate the days difference as "7" before submitting in leave count box the values on run time Using Javascript

Below is the text values codes.

```
Date From: <input type="date" name="from">
Date To: <input type="date" name="to">
Leave Count: <input type="text" name="leavecount">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-javascript