# Calculating future dates based on curent date within inline editor for Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I am using the inline editor for Dialogflow to manipulate user data and query my database in.js, with that, I also want the chatbot to answer questions like:

"When is my next Art test."

As the admin I know Art tests are every 3 weeks on Wednesday throughout the year, but how do I translate that into a chatbot response, something like;

"Your next art test is Wednesday 8th August", Or even, "Your next test is Today!"

I have looked at [this](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=-d7WptXGPzn) which is different ways to initiate js times, but none seem to fit what I'm looking for.

I have created a function for time as below, which is where I assume I'd have to make the calculation:

```
  function getDate(agent){
      var today = new Date();
  }
```

And the response would be something like:

```
function getTestDate(agent){
        agent.add('Your next test date is' + today); #etc   
}
```

Lastly I have seen this other post on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) calculating days between two dates, whilst this could work I'm not too sure how I can implement this into a Dialogflow environment.

I don't think moment.js can work within the inline editor, but if it did, It looks like it would be easy, per the example [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow();     // 4 years ago
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(true); // 4 years
```

Then I could simply do the fromNow() command in each function for different dates, and idea how something like this could be interpreted to normal js?

**UPDATE**

Not got anywhere with this yet but had another idea, is there anyway to identify the month and from there trigger a response? For example can I create a function that identifies the date right now, then i'll be able to write the 3/4 test dates as a text response:

```
function (getTestDate(agent){
        if(date) == May
} agent.add('Tests for May are....etc')
```

Comment: Inside of `getTestDate`, how can `getTestDate` be falsy?

Comment: are u sure? function getTestDate(agent){ if (getTestDate){}}

Comment: Gah, I don't even know what I was doing there.

Comment: Updated, that still covers my question but without the dodgy code.

Comment: just install moment js your work would be easier

Comment: I am using the inline editor in Dialogflow, not sure how limited I am using that? But happy to give anything a try, still not sure how I'd do what I am trying to achieve in the question even using moment js.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not exactly what I wanted but the closest I can get to what I want is declaring a test date, then creating if statements to suggest IF today is before a certain date, then i know to respond with the next closest date, and so on.

```
function getTestDate(agent){
        var today = new Date();
        var testDate= new Date("08/08/2018");
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(testDate.getTime() - today.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

        if (today < testDate){
            agent.add('Your next test date is in ' + diffDays + 'days, at 9pm on Wednesday');
        }else if (today > testDate) {
            agent.add('Your test date was on Wednesday 8th August 2018');
        }else if (today == testDate){
            agent.add('Your test is today, Wednesday 8th August 2018');
        }
```

Again, not ideal as I know have to create a variety of functions for different times, but get's the job done. 
If you have any other suggestions please feel free to suggest.