# How to get number of days from two date objects for the following date format

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript and learning about the `Date` object. I am working on an excercise that gives me two `date objects`, and I would like to get the number of days between them. To do this I will take the `endate - startdate`. How can I go about doing this since the dates are in this format below.

Edit1: I have looked at the previous asked questions but they don't answer how to format the dates I am asking.

```
startdate => 2019-04-01T04:00:00.000Z
endate => 2019-04-08T04:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to Date because the strings follow the ***ISO 8601*** format, subtract and finally calculate the days.

```js
let startdate = "2019-04-01T04:00:00.000Z";
let endate = "2019-04-08T04:00:00.000Z";
let days = (new Date(endate) - new Date(startdate)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

console.log(days);
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me! Thank you so much.