# How do I calculate dates and show the remaining dates with an input fied?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to come to a code that show is a certain date is still valid and for how long.

The code I've come up with so far can check if the date is not in the future. But I'm unable to how if the date is still valid or not.
Can someone help me?

```js
function TheorieFunction() {
  var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('DateTheorie').value);
  var today = new Date();

  if (startDate.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
    alert("Error: Given date is in the future");
  }
  if (startDate.getTime() > today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 3) {
    document.getElementById("Theorietxt").innerHTML = "Your theorie is still valid for" + today.getTime() - startDate.getTime()
    "days";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Theorietxt").innerHTML = "Your theorie is invalid";
  }
}
```

```html
Date theorie exam: <input type="date" id="DateTheorie" value="2017-01-01">
<span class="validity"></span>
<button id=Btntheorie onclick="TheorieFunction()">Check</button>

<p id="Theorietxt"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "date is still valid"? Try to follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The inputed date can not be older than 3 years from today
If longer ago than 3 years the user should be told his exam is no longer valid

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a solution like this? Making use of date difference function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) post

**Edit:** i have used only basic year difference calculation like 356 days per year. If you want the exact year difference you need to go for [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) [difference function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

You can find the implementation using moment js in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzhfn4cv/)

```js
function TheorieFunction() {
    var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('DateTheorie').value);
    var today = new Date();

    if (startDate.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
        alert("Error: Given date is in the future");
        return;
    }            
    if(startDate.valueOf() !== NaN) {
        const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((today - startDate) / oneDay));
        if (diffDays < 3 * 365) {
            document.getElementById("Theorietxt").innerHTML="Your theorie is still valid for" + (diffDays) +  "days";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("Theorietxt").innerHTML="Your theorie is invalid";
        }
    } else {
        alert('In Valid Date selected');
    }
}
```

```html
Date theorie exam: <input type="date" id="DateTheorie" value="2020-01-01" />
<span class="validity"></span>
<button id="Btntheorie" onclick="TheorieFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="Theorietxt"></p>
```

Comment: Yes, this is sort of what I'm looking for.
But the " else if (startDate.getTime() < today.getTime())" should be different.
If the date is less than 3 years from today: "Theorie is still valid until (date+3years) [instead of valid for ... days]
Else: "Your theorie is invalid"

Any solution to that?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: @wendyschollaert I have updated the solution please check.

Comment: You are my hero !!

Comment: @wendyschollaert if this is the solution that you are looking for, please approve my answer. :)