# How to get the n umber of days left until a specific day

Tags: javascript

How can I get the number of days left until next birthday from this array of objects?

```
const people = [
    { name: 'Bill', dob: new Date('07/11/1949') },
    { name: 'Will', dob: new Date('02/21/1979') }
]
```

So basically I need how many days there are from today until the birth date.

I tried to extract the month and day from the dob like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    const personDob = people[i].dob
    const personBirthMonth = new Date(personDob).getMonth() + 1
    const personDayOfBirth = new Date(personDob).getUTCDate() +1
}
```

I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) but I'm kind of confused because I don't need to compare the full year, only the months and days I guess.

I'm not sure how to get the remaining days left.

Comment: Hint: You probably want to compare the current date to the birthday in this year or the next year.

Comment: so where do you want to save or put the days till birthday ? In the same object as another attribute besides `name` and `dob` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

If the date **is past**, then plus one year on the year of now.

##### Just a simple example, please modify yourself.

So code:

```js
const now = new Date(),
    date = new Date("07/11/1949");

if (now.getMonth() > date.getMonth() || (now.getMonth() == date.getMonth() && now.getDate() > date.getDate()))
    date.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
const days = (date.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 86400000;
console.log(days + " days left.");
```

Answer (score 0):

May you could try to extract like this

```
currDate = new Date()
people.forEach((person)=>{
     let nextbd = person.dob;
     nextbd.setFullYear(currDate.getFullYear() + 1);
     let diffTime = Math.abs(nextbd  - currDate);
     let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

   console.log(person.name+" has next birdthday after " +diffDays +" days");
     
})
```

Comment: When his birthday is on like `10/21` or etc..
`Will has next birdthday after 397 days`